# setting up virtual host on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I have an ec2 instance which is apache web server, 
why when I am creating virtual host for website I can use only private ec2 IP? this IP is changing everytime when I stop and start an instance, so I don't think I can relay on this. 
I just thought elastic IP should work but I seems like it's not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you associated your ec2 instance with allocated elastic IP, you can rely on Public DNS [ ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com ]. It doesn't change on start/stop.

For more info 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

Comment: Also, keep in mind that your DNS changes after you associate the Elastic IP.

Answer (score 0):

1) Associated your ec2 instance with allocated elastic IP.

2) Configure Route 53

Configuration info : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-configure-route53.html

3) Set provided DNS in your domain panel.